# Symfony/Doctrine: Add property of entity by admin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to build a admin website with Symfony, where a user can add properties for Doctrine entities dynamically and they are mapped to database rows?

Example: the user wants to add the property "name" to the entity "customer" and defines it as an VarChar 100.

Maybe there is a package which can handle this task?

One hacky solution could be to parse the entity file and add the property. Then update the database.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do is the following:

Use the SensioGeneratorBundle, which also can extends entities:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html

For making this command available to the admin user without using the shell, one could use

[Using linux 'dialog' command from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711904/using-linux-dialog-command-from-php/11368199)